# How to fetch image from local computer with Picasso then display it to android app with Java

Tags: java, android

### This line of code works

`Picasso.with(context).load("https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/advertise.png").into(holder.imageView);`

### This line of code doesn't work

`Picasso.with(context).load("/Users/jz/Desktop/Pictures/kigali.png").into(holder.imageView);`

How can is solve the issue ?
is it my file permission ?

Answer (score 3):

This won't work. Your computer is NOT local for your Android - even if you run your app on emulator running on that computer as it runs virtual machine thus needs to be considered separate device in this context. To make any file from your machine available you need any server (like apach, nginx) and make your computer reachable from the network (can be local only). Then you can reach these files using network i. e. via same type of `http://` request you already have.

Comment: After installing Picasso, Volley and fetching other json formated data the images still refused to be displayed but   I can see texts fetched from local server

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use image or icon inside app you can put it into assets folder and use like this

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drowable.icon_main_page).into(holder.imageView)
```